# Intermittent SQL Server Connection Failure

Tags: c#, sql-server

So we keep getting these errors, intermittently.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Notice the part there about Named Pipes Provider?

Here is my connection string:

```
var conStr = "Data Source=tcp:MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=myusername;Password=myuserpassword;Max Pool Size=100;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=120;";
```

In my connection string you'll notice I specify TCP. So this error message is crazy to me. I cant replicate this with any sort of reliability, but, it happens every, single, day. Nothing in the event logs, sql server log, surrounding application logs, nothing. Also when it happens there are at least 2k other connections from various other applications/servers throughout the enterprise that dont have this issue, until they do.

I should add that these are all VMs living inside of a VSphere cluster with 40Gbps connectivity between all the various hosts.

I've read every single hit 3 pages deep on google search results (yep, I went 3 whole pages deep). I'm lost.

1. What does the exception really mean?
2. Why does it say its using Named Pipers Provider?

Per request:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conStr = "Data Source=tcp:MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=myusername;Password=myuserpassword;Max Pool Size=100;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=120;";
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                con.Open();
            }
        }
```

Comment: DNS issues perhaps. Have you tried the IP address instead of the name?

Comment: If it's intermittent and seems to be using different provider maybe it's different connection that errors?

Comment: 1) The app failed to connect to the server 2) I don't know but it just does. I suspect it tries all connection types - Named Pipes, TCP etc - and then when _none_ of them can connect, for some reason it decides to blame the Named Pipes Provider in the error message.

Comment: @stuartd - well of course named pipes fails, its turned off!! all of our connection strings force tcp.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. Like I say, I don't know why the error message says that, and perhaps I shouldn't have speculated on why it does, but in my experience it just does and it's a red herring.

Comment: It could happen due to various reasons: Faulty network connectivity, disabled protocols on server or client side, client alias overriding your connection string, a bug in code is using a different connection string.  In any case, connection faults are sometimes outside your control and your code must be ready for failures and dealing with them.